# Trouble with handlebars-- nested iterations logging same value when should be different

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Title says it all. I'm trying to nest iterations with handlebars but can't seem to get it right. I've parsed down the code to what I've deemed to be the bare essentials, but if my problem lies somewhere else I can post all of it.

Here is the array I'm returning as 'data'.

```js
[{
  id: 4,
  title: 'Think Python',
  cover_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/think_python.jpg',
  book_id: 2,
  author_id: 4,
  firstname: 'Allen',
  lastname: 'Downey',
  bio: 'Allen Downey is a Professor of Computer Science at Olin College of Engineering. He has taught at Wellesley College, Colby College and U.C. Berkeley. He has a Ph.D. in Computer Science from U.C. Berkeley and Master\'s and Bachelor\'s degrees from MIT.',
  author_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/allen_downey.jpg',
  authors: [{
    name: 'Allen Downey',
    id: 4
  }]
} {
  id: 5,
  title: 'Learning React Native',
  cover_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/learning_react_native.jpg',
  book_id: 3,
  author_id: 5,
  firstname: 'Bonnie',
  lastname: 'Eisenman',
  bio: 'Bonnie,Eisenman,"Bonnie Eisenman is a software engineer at Codecademy, with previous experience at Fog Creek Software and Google. She has spoken at several conferences on topics ranging from ReactJS to musical programming and Arduinos. In her spare time, she enjoys building electronic musical instruments, tinkering with hardware projects, and laser-cutting chocolate. Find her on Twitter as @brindelle.',
  author_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/bonnie_eisenman.jpg',
  authors: [{
    name: 'Bonnie Eisenman',
    id: 5
  }]
} {
  id: 6,
  title: 'You Don\'t Know JS: ES6 & Beyond',
  cover_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/es6_and_beyond.jpg',
  book_id: 4,
  author_id: 6,
  firstname: 'Kyle',
  lastname: 'Simpson',
  bio: 'Kyle Simpson is an Open Web Evangelist who\'s passionate about all things JavaScript. He\'s an author, workshop trainer, tech speaker, and OSS contributor/leader.',
  author_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/kyle_simpson.jpg',
  authors: [{
    name: 'Kyle Simpson',
    id: 6
  }]
} {
  id: 6,
  title: 'You Don\'t Know JS: Scope & Closures',
  cover_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/scope_and_closures.jpg',
  book_id: 5,
  author_id: 6,
  firstname: 'Kyle',
  lastname: 'Simpson',
  bio: 'Kyle Simpson is an Open Web Evangelist who\'s passionate about all things JavaScript. He\'s an author, workshop trainer, tech speaker, and OSS contributor/leader.',
  author_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/kyle_simpson.jpg',
  authors: [{
    name: 'Kyle Simpson',
    id: 6
  }]
} {
  id: 6,
  title: 'You Don\'t Know JS: Async & Performance',
  cover_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/async_and_performance.jpg',
  book_id: 6,
  author_id: 6,
  firstname: 'Kyle',
  lastname: 'Simpson',
  bio: 'Kyle Simpson is an Open Web Evangelist who\'s passionate about all things JavaScript. He\'s an author, workshop trainer, tech speaker, and OSS contributor/leader.',
  author_url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assessment-images/galvanize_reads/photos/kyle_simpson.jpg',
  authors: [{
    name: 'Kyle Simpson',
    id: 6
  }]
} {
  id: 13,
  title: 'A Darker Shade of Magic',
  cover_url: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51RYeVqlj9L._SX331_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
  book_id: 10,
  author_id: 13,
  firstname: 'Victoria E.',
  lastname: 'Schwab',
  bio: 'Victoria [V.E.] Schwab is an American author known for her adult books under V.E. Schwab and her young adult and middle grade books under Victoria Schwab. Most notable publications include: Vicious and A Darker Shade of Magic.',
  author_url: 'http://prodimage.images-bn.com/cimages/0000012524053_p0_v1_s280x185.jpg',
  authors: [{
    name: 'Victoria E. Schwab',
    id: 13
  }]
} {
  id: 14,
  title: 'Harry Potter',
  description: 'A magical wizard finds his way in the world.',
  cover_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bf/Harry_Potter_and_the_Sorcerer\'s_Stone.jpg',
  book_id: 11,
  author_id: 14,
  firstname: 'J. K. ',
  lastname: 'Rowling',
  bio: 'A brilliant Englishwoman. ',
  author_url: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/703332968232820739/vu_rCwh5.jpg',
  authors: [{
    name: 'J. K.  Rowling',
    id: 14
  }]
}]
```

And the handlebars:

```
{{#data}}
{{#each this.authors}}
<ul>{{name}}</ul>
{{/each}}
{{/data}}
```

And the handlebars output is 10 JK Rowlings, not multiple authors. I can't for the life of me figure this out. Have tried various handlebars formats and still can't get it right.

My first post here. Sorry if this isn't clear. Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Edit: And yes, if it was only one author per object I wouldn't have to use a nested array, but there are some instances (not in example) when multiple authors exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `data` value is invalid.  The items in the top-level array are not separated by commas.

I was able to get this working fine on http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ once I added those commas:

[image]

Perhaps your data is not being set as you believe it is?

Comment: Hey Scott-- thanks for your feedback. After a lot of hemming and hawing I did get it to work. I actually still don't know why JK Rowling was cloning herself-- I ended up rewriting the code that generated the array I posted above and that made it all work. Probably for the better, too-- the rewrite was much more elegant code, at only 60% the length if the original and a lot more readable. Because of your comment I knew it wasn't an issue on the handlebars side, so you definitely saved me some head scratching. Thanks again!